# When is renunciation of citizenship effective from?

Tags: united-kingdom, citizenship

Say a person is a dual UK/Australian citizen, and they decide to renounce their UK citizenship.  They submit the required paperwork to perform an effective renunciation.

What date will their renunciation be effective from (i.e, what is the earliest date from which they are no longer considered a UK citizen under UK law)?  Is it:

- The date on which they sign their renunciation paperwork?
- The date their paperwork is posted?
- The date their paperwork is confirmed as being received?
- The date on which their renunciation is formally confirmed?

...or something else entirely?

Answer (score 3):

According to https://www.gov.uk/renounce-british-nationality/after-youve-applied:

> 3. After you've applied
>
> You’ll get a ‘declaration of renunciation’ if your application is successful. This will be your application form, officially signed and stamped.
>
> The date your citizenship or status stops will be shown on the form.